# Finding 12-hour format Time in a String with Regex in Java

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to find a time in a String using a regex in Java. Here's the regex:

```
\d{1,2}?:\d\d(?)(am|pm)??
```

That *should*  look for 1 or 2 digits, followed by a colon, two more digits, then either "am" or "pm" (irrespective of case).

It mostly works, but if I wrap that entire regex in a capture group, I only get hh:mm.  For example, "12:34am" returns just "12:34". No "am".

**UPDATE: Full code example**

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d{1,2}?:\\d\\d(?)(am|pm)??");
Matcher matcher = p.matcher("12:34AM");
Assert.assertTrue(matcher.find());
Assert.assertEquals("12:34AM", matcher.group());
```

Anyone have any idea why?

Comment: You're looking at the wrong groups.  Try group 0.  Next time, please post an [mcve], not just the bits you think are relevant.  Guessing at what you're doing is not optimal

Comment: Why are there so many question marks? Am I missing something or should this just be `\d{1,2}?:\d\d(am|pm)` or if the am/pm is optional, `\d{1,2}:\d\d(am|pm)?`

Comment: @3ocene I don't believe it's a valid regex as it is anyway.  What is `(?)`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Java regex engine so I was thinking it might have made the next group non-capturing but after googling it seems that it's the same as any other engine: `\d{1,2}:\d\d(?:am|pm)`

Comment: @Tibrogargan, I've updated the code with a full example for my original question. I'll now try incorporating the various changes mentioned to see if I can get to the bottom of this. :)

Comment: @jasondlee the capturing group for am/pm is optional lazy.. as it's at the end of the match, it will never be used (exception being the use of .matches), use a single ? to make it optional greedy. Not sure about the (?) though.

Comment: @jasondlee You need to describe what you're seeing.  I'm assuming the first assertion passes and the 2nd one fails?  (Because while it's finding your pattern correctly, the group it's returning is null, since `(am|pm)` does NOT match "AM".  The big issue is that you're not surrounding the entire thing in a group at all, except for the `(am|pm)`

Comment: @Tibrogargan, yes. Sorry. That's exactly what I'm seeing. The return from the group is incorrect (missing the "am"). And you're right. I didn't enclose the regex in a group. I hastily threw that test method together and missed the key part. :) Adding that, however, it still didn't work. The regex itself is broken. I'm far from a regex expert and it clearly shows. :) The solution from Elaysin below seems to do the trick, fwiw. Now I just need to compare the two to learn why. :)

Comment: @jasondlee Sebastian Proske's regex is better - it will match actual times as opposed to things that aren't times (like 67:89aM)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of your current pattern, you might want to use `\b(?:[01]?\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]?\d(?:[ap]m)?\b` to match times, with the case-insensitive flag set or even use alternatives to distinct between 24h notation and 12h notation with `am`/`pm`

Your current pattern uses a lazy optional pattern to match the `am`/`pm` (`(am|pm)??`), as this is at the end of the pattern, it will never match (except when used in the context of .matches() instead of .find(), as it forces a full match).

I'm honestly not sure about the `(?)` in your pattern.

Comment: I think this might actually do it, more or less. I tried the regex unchanged and failed to find matches, but if I use `(?:[01]?\\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]?\\d *(?:am|AM|pm|PM)?`, it works as expected. I'm not a real big fan of the AM/PM handling at the end, but I do have it capturing that now, which is my primary concern, so I can optimize that as time permits.

Comment: Yep, you have to use double backslashes for the actual use, but as you wrote your regex pattern in standard notation in your question, I thought it would be fine to use.

Answer (score 1):

As you are matching against 12 hour format so there are many bound to cover so never use `\d` because it will accept any number number input given by user and your regex will fail against these invalid cases like  `13:32am` `22:23am` or many others non-12 hour formats

so to make it robust use

[**`\\b(1[012]|0[1-9]):([0-5][0-9])(\\s)?([Aa]|[pP])[mM]`**](https://regex101.com/r/FQQEGF/3)

`\\b(1[012]|0?[1-9]):` `\\b` word boundary then either `10,11,12` or `0` with `1-9`

`:([0-5][0-9])` `:` character match digits from `00-59`

`(\\s)?` there can be a single space

`([Aa]|[pP])[mM]` either am,AM or pm,PM etc

Complete code would be

```
    Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile("\\b(1[012]|0[1-9]):([0-5][0-9])(\\s)?([Aa]|[pP])[mM]");
    Matcher matcher=pattern.matcher("12:23am 12:6am  ds  13:32am dwdw c 01:12am ded 1:21am");

    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
```

To make it more flexible for inputs like `1:21am` and `1:1am` use

[**`\\b(1[012]|0?[1-9]):([0-5]?[0-9])(\\s)?([Aa]|[pP])[mM]`**](https://regex101.com/r/Z7AniN/1)

Answer (score 0):

This gets your group correctly with modifications to the test string to match case, remove extraneous question marks and to add the surrounding group.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d{1,2}:\\d\\d(AM|PM)?)");
Matcher matcher = p.matcher("12:34AM");
Assert.assertTrue(matcher.find());
Assert.assertEquals("12:34AM", matcher.group());
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry i edited: `\d?\d:\d?\d["a"|"p"|"A"|"P"]["m"|"M"]`

Comment: This doesn't seem to really answer the original question. Yes, it may match a time, but it will also match many other things like `1234567890:0987654321|"`